# Ways to shrink/minimize snapshot size [Digital Ocean]

Tags: virtual-machine, vps

Given that Digital Ocean is now going to start charging for snapshots by the GB, are there any tips or techniques to minimizing the size of a snapshot?

I have one snapshot of an system I use for periodic development and testing of some web apps that has ballooned to 2GB, while some others are only a few hundred megs.

I'm assuming if you're starting from scratch, things like avoiding updates and creating new files/editing many OS files might be good. Anything else?

*EDIT:* This question is aimed primarily at Digital Ocean, but might be applicable to other VPS systems and VMs.

Comment: Whilst I think this is an interesting question, it may be too broad to be a good fit here...

Comment: What you can do entirely depends on the contents virtual machine itself.  I know with VMWare you can "delete" snapshots in order, to merge the delta differences, at that point you can compress virtual hdd.  Shrinking the HDD, is a great deal harder, depending on the OS.

Comment: So I guess I forgot to put it in the title, but this is essentially aimed at Digital Ocean. There's no D-O tag on SuperUser, but someone complained when I asked at StackOverflow, which does have a Digital Ocean tag. I'll add that to my question.

Comment: The only way its applicable is if it applies to other Hypervisors.  It only applying to DigitalOcean makes it out of scope.  Please don't cross-post across more SE websites, if its not on topic here, allow us to migrate it.

Comment: [Shrink a VM hardisk size](http://superuser.com/questions/1079991/shrink-a-vm-hardisk-size)